# Navbar above a slider

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-4

I'm building a website at the moment, and have a problem with the nav bar. 
I have a slider, and I want the navbar to be above a slider. However, my nav is pushing down the slider. The navbar should be above the slider images, with transparency, so I can see the navbar and the image behind it.

I'm using bootstrap and changing some styles, to make the elements look as I want them to look.

Here is the HTML and CSS, what should I change or add?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.intro-slider').slick {
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: false
  });
});
```

```css
.intro-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default,
.container-fluid,
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form,
.navbar-collapse.collapse,
.navbar navbar-default {
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
}

img {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">


<body>
  <div style="" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="navfont2">
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> +1 809 974 7826</p>
      </li>
      <li class="navfont2">
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> orestes@mintech.do</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-- navbar start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div style="" class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div style="" class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img style="width: 175px;" src="images/mintech.png"></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Equipo</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <!-- navbar end -->
  <div class="intro-slider col-xs-12">
    <div><img src="https://www.almanac.com/sites/default/files/birth_month_flowers-primary-1920x1280px_pixabay.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://balconygardenweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/most-poisonous-flowers-3_mini.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/57613434/large.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean the navbar is pushing down the slider? Do you want the slider to be higher? Can you be more specific what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the navbar to be above the slider images, with transparency, so I can see the navbar and the image behind it.

Comment: Please modify this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wne5qq5q/1/) and replicate your problem, I am unable to understand the error.

Comment: @arolleunam If you wanted your navbar to be above the slider div in 3D space I made a snippet that might help you out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position your navbar above your slider. I had to use relative positioning too to push the slider up a bit. All my code is commented to help you follow. Lastly I made the navbar transparent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.intro-slider').slick {
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: false
  });
});
```

```css
.intro-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default,
.container-fluid,
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form,
.navbar-collapse.collapse,
.navbar navbar-default {
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
}

img {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}


/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ new styles below ///////////////////////////// */
hr {
  display: none; /* margins on hr were pushing gallery down */
}
body .navbar { /* place navbar atop slider */
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
.intro-slider { /* move slider up */
  position: relative;
  top: -3rem;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">


<body>
  <div style="" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="navfont2">
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> +1 809 974 7826</p>
      </li>
      <li class="navfont2">
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> orestes@mintech.do</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-- navbar start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div style="" class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div style="" class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img style="width: 175px;" src="images/mintech.png"></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Equipo</a></li>
          <li class="navfont"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <!-- navbar end -->
  <div class="intro-slider col-xs-12">
    <div><img src="https://www.almanac.com/sites/default/files/birth_month_flowers-primary-1920x1280px_pixabay.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://balconygardenweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/most-poisonous-flowers-3_mini.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/57613434/large.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```